# Saving a picture from a text message to my phone (asus, zenfone)

Tags: sms, photos

how do I save pictures to my phone that I receive through a text message?

Comment: Have you tried long-pressing on the picture?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of four options:

1. Try long pressing on the picture (either in the message list or after tapping on it in full screen mode).
2. Press the physical or software (Three dots) menu button and select something like: 'Download' or 'Save to phone'
3. Tap to view the image full screen and screenshot it, then crop it using the gallery app
4. Download a different sms app that allows you to save pictures, then set it as default (e.g. Google Messenger 
   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging&hl=en